# _pickle.PicklingError when trying to read a table from BigQuery and save it as a dataframe using Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-client

What is the best way to read a BigQuery table from Airflow and save the result as a dataframe?
I have a python module to read the table and can run this locally to fetch the table:

```
def reading(ds, **kwargs):
    project_id = '{project-id}'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/usr/local/airflow/extras/credentials.json')
    bqclient = bq.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
    query_string = bqclient.query("""
        SELECT *
        FROM   `{project-id}.{schema-name}.{table-name}`""")

    dataframe = (
        bqclient.query(query_string)
        .result()
        .to_dataframe(
            create_bqstorage_client=True,
        )
    )
    print(dataframe.head())
```

However, when I am trying to call the module in an Airflow DAG, it gives an error:

**_pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.
Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.**

Here is the full error stack:

```
*** Reading local file: /usr/local/airflow/logs/test_BQ_read/BQ_reading/2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00/1.log
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,401] {taskinstance.py:897} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_BQ_read.BQ_reading 2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,434] {taskinstance.py:897} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_BQ_read.BQ_reading 2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,434] {taskinstance.py:1088} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,434] {taskinstance.py:1089} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,434] {taskinstance.py:1090} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,454] {taskinstance.py:1108} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): BQ_reading> on 2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,469] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 37080 to run task
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,492] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_BQ_read', 'BQ_reading', '2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00', '--job-id', '538', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_BQ_read.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp3m9gbm14', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmps5fthy88']
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,494] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 538: Subtask BQ_reading
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,606] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_BQ_read.BQ_reading 2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00 [running]> on host ffce3e5ffe75
[2021-09-22 09:16:05,737] {taskinstance.py:1303} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_BQ_read
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=BQ_reading
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-09-22T09:16:02.147166+00:00
[2021-09-22 09:16:06,165] {taskinstance.py:1502} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1158, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1362, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 150, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 161, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/test_BQ_read.py", line 43, in reading
    result = bqclient.query(query_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3223, in query
    query_job._begin(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1138, in _begin
    super(QueryJob, self)._begin(client=client, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 468, in _begin
    data=self.to_api_repr(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 819, in to_api_repr
    configuration = self._configuration.to_api_repr()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 605, in to_api_repr
    resource = copy.deepcopy(self._properties)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 241, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 241, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 281, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 241, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 167, in __getstate__
    "Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.",
_pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.
Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.
[2021-09-22 09:16:06,172] {taskinstance.py:1552} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_BQ_read, task_id=BQ_reading, execution_date=20210922T091602, start_date=20210922T091605, end_date=20210922T091606
[2021-09-22 09:16:06,368] {local_task_job.py:153} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Any suggestions on how to read the table correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it worked for me by making changes to the python module

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models
from airflow.models import Variable
import pandas as pd
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def reading(ds, **kwargs):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/usr/local/airflow/extras/credentials.json')
    project_id = '{project-id}'
    bqclient = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

    # Download a table.
    table = bigquery.TableReference.from_string(
        ""project-id}.{schema_name}.{table_name}"
    )

    rows = bqclient.list_rows(
        table,
    )

    dataframe = rows.to_dataframe(
        create_bqstorage_client=True,
    )
    print(dataframe.head())

with models.DAG(
    'test_BQ_read',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date='2021-09-22',
    tags=["example"],
    catchup=False
) as dag:

    BQ_reading = PythonOperator(
        task_id='BQ_reading',
        python_callable=reading,
    )
```

Probably something to do with pandas and BigQuery causing the pickle error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to show the DAG you are using - but my guess in your operator you try to instantiate google client in **init** of your operator (possibly you create and assign Hook to some field there). This is quite wrong - the hooks should only be instantiated inside "execute" method of the operator and should not be stored in the Operator object when constructed.

See any of the Google operators: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators